# in Sql, how to calculate the values based on range?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I created a table and get a count column after performing other operations. Now, I want to calculate the value based on the range in which the count lies. If it crosses the range then consider the max range.

For example:
Example 1

```
Count  | Min  |  Max |  Amount
----------------------------------
  4    | 1    |   1  |    5
  4    | 2    |   2  |    10
  4    | 3    |   5  |    12
  4    | 6    |   8  |    15
```

Example 2

```
Count  | Min  |  Max |  Amount
---------------------------------
  4    | 1    |   1  |    5
  4    | 2    |   2  |    10
```

**Results:** 
What I want the results. 
For Example 1: Count (4) lies between Min(3) and Max(4) so we need to consider the amount from that row and the result like below.

```
Count  | Min  |  Max |  Amount  |  Total Amount
-----------------------------------------------
  4    | 3    |   5  |    12    |     48       (Count * Amount)
```

For Example 2: Count (4) crosses all the limits so we need to consider the amount from higher range row and the result like below.

```
Count  | Min  |  Max |  Amount  |  Total Amount
-----------------------------------------------
  4    | 2    |   2  |    10    |     20        (Max * Amount)
```

Comment: What have you tried? Why didn't it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want:

```
select top (1) t.*, (amount * count)
from t
order by (case when count between min and max then 1 else 2 end),
          amount desc;
```

Note:  `count`, `min`, and `max` are poor choices for column names because they are SQL built-in functions.

Comment: yes, I am using different names in actual application. Thanks, it works, I just modify a little bit in order to achieve the second example.

SELECT top (1) a.*, CASE WHEN count > Max THEN Max ELSE Count END * Amount 
from t   order by (case when count between min and max then 1 else 2 end), amount desc

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are expecting ?

**Sample Data**

```
SELECT * INTO #TAB FROM (
 SELECT 4 AS COUNTNO ,1 AS MINNO,1 AS MAXNO ,5  AS AMOUNT
    UNION ALL 
 SELECT 4,2,2,10
   UNION ALL 
 SELECT 4,3,5,12
   UNION ALL 
 SELECT 4,6,8,15 )AS A
```

**Query:**

```
SELECT T.*,
IIF(COUNTNO BETWEEN MINNO AND MAXNO , CountNO * Amount ,MAXNO*AMOUNT)ExpectedOp FROM  #TAB T
```

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/7ea22/4)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
create table test(count int ,
                  min int,
                  max int,
                 amount int)
insert test values(4,3,5,12),
                  (4,2,2,10)
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT *,CASE
            WHEN count >min and count<=max
               THEN Count * Amount
               ELSE Max * Amount
       END as TotalAmount
FROM test
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/7ea22/4/0)**:

```
| count | min | max | amount | TotalAmount |
|-------|-----|-----|--------|-------------|
|     4 |   3 |   5 |     12 |          48 |
|     4 |   2 |   2 |     10 |          20 |
```